# Ошибка при сложении массива с константой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой кусок кода

```
n = 0
while n < Nj:
    uj = Xin * Winj[:,n]
    Uj[n] = Bj[n] + uj.sum
    n += 1
```

При выполнении программы возникает следующая ошибка:

```
 Uj[n] = Bj[n] + uj.sum
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and
>   'builtin_function_or_method'

Далее изменил код следующим образом:

```
n = 0
while n < Nj:
    uj = Xin * Winj[:,n]
    u = uj.sum
    Uj[n] = Bj[n] + u
    n += 1
```

Ошибка осталась:

```
Uj[n] = Bj[n] + u
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and
>   'builtin_function_or_method'

В чем причина возникновения данной ошибки?

Comment: Нельзя сложить число Bj[n] и метод uj.sum.

Comment: А что Вы хотите получить?
Суть ошибки в том что Вы float пытаетесь сложить с функцией.

Comment: по вашему коду не понятно что вы с чем складываете... Используете ли вы NumPy или Vanila Python lists...

Comment: Использую NumPy

Comment: @АлексейВоронов, если вы используете NumPy то скорее всего можно было обойтись без циклов...

Comment: Подскажите решение без циклов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу утверждать наверняка, так как из кода непонятно, какой тип имеет uj.

Но, скорее всего, вам нужно просто добавить скобки у метода sum:

```
# Для первого варианта кода
Uj[n] = Bj[n] + uj.sum()
```

или

```
# Для второго варианта кода
u = uj.sum()
```

Дело в том, что без скобок вы получаете не результат выполнения метода, а просто ссылку на этот метод.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Забыл про скобки.